# Use Satchmo subscription to the store itself

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, satchmo

I'm trying to set up Satchmo, and I found this cool Subscription Product, but what I want is make a members-only section on the site (a multiple store website) itself. In other words, I want the users to make subscriptions to be able to use certain features. Is this possible in Satchmo?

I guess if my website is called xyz.com then I can create xyz store on the system and let it have a subscription product, but can I integrate it with the Django login system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be easier than in the plain Django.
You can catch the signal `django.core.signals.request_started` or write a context processor or a middleware. Then you test that the subscipton is still a valid and save the result to a context variable (in order to can hide some feature by a template) or generate an error/redirest if the page should not be displayd

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `satchmo_store.shop.signals.order_success` and include in your listener all the required steps for self subscription (user to group, object creation etc.,..).